# Python: If multiple line consists abcd1234 , can I find abcd* and replace?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python scripting in order to remove the strings from the text file.

In my text file I have contents as,

abcdefgh

abc

abcd

abcdef

abcd_123

I need to remove the data abcdefgh, abcdef, abcd_123 from the file and used the script as below by finding abcd* which in general should find all the alphabets/numbers after abcd, but here it is not working as expected. Can you please help in this on how to handle such data?

Expected output should be

abc

abcd

Ex:

````
    with open('output_file.txt','w') as out_file:
        for line_replace in in_file:
            out_file.write(line_replace.replace('abcd*',''))```
````

Comment: You can't use `*` as a "wild card" character with string functions. If you really need to do that, the solution is the `re` module. Be warned, it's learning curve is a bit steep. This how-to is excellent: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Comment: Thanks for reminding on re module. Let me try to explore a bit and see the condition if I can really implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here what i see is you are not opening the "in_file" file that you will write to it the data
you can do it by :

in_file = open("file.txt",a+)

then :

```
in_file = open("file.txt",a+)
with open('output_file.txt','w') as out_file:
        for line in out_file:
            if not line.startswith("abcd"):
                in_file.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks Yassir, I did some tweak over the script and got it work.
```if not line.startswith("abcd"):``` worked for me

Comment: Happy to hear that!